# Get indexed jQuery object from multi-object selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I realize that I can use `get(#)` or `[#]` to get the DOM object contained within a "multi-object" jQuery object. I am also familiar with iterating over a jQuery object, but in this case, I'd like to access the jQuery sub-object at an index.  Is this possible (it seems like it should be given this existence of `.first()` and `.last()`)?

Comment: Use `.eq()`. http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has the `.eq()` method for this purpose.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/eq/